# Changing the style of the active CSS tab and top color

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

I am using a CSS only styled themed menu and would like to add a top, left and right border of the active tab, but take away the bottom and also white out the blank space in the tab. For this example, I have attached a picture of the current result and desired result along with the CSS and HTML markup in question.

Current output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

CSS:

```
.tabs {

      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      max-width: 700px;
      background: #efefef;

    }

    .input {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .label {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px 30px;
      background: #e5e5e5;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #7f7f7f;
      transition: background 0.1s, color 0.1s;
    }

    .label:hover {
      background: #d8d8d8;
    }

    .label:active {
      background: #ccc;
    }

    .input:focus + .label {
      z-index: 1;
        border-bottom: -2px solid red;
    }

    .input:checked + .label {
      background: #fff;
      color: #000;
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .label {
        width: auto;
      }
    }

    .panel {
      display: none;
      padding: 20px 30px 30px;
      background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      .panel {
        order: 99;
      }
    }

    .input:checked + .label + .panel {
      display: block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-1" checked="checked" class="input"/>
  <label for="tab-1" class="label">Orange</label>
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Orange</h1>
    <p>The orange (specifically, the sweet orange) is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus × sinensis in the family Rutaceae</p>
    <p>The fruit of the Citrus × sinensis is considered a sweet orange, whereas the fruit of the Citrus × aurantium is considered a bitter orange. The sweet orange reproduces asexually (apomixis through nucellar embryony); varieties of sweet orange arise through mutations.</p>
  </div>

  <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-2" class="input"/>
  <label for="tab-2" class="label">Tangerine</label>
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Tangerine</h1>
    <p>The tangerine (Citrus tangerina) is an orange-colored citrus fruit that is closely related to, or possibly a type of, mandarin orange (Citrus reticulata).</p>
    <p>The name was first used for fruit coming from Tangier, Morocco, described as a mandarin variety. Under the Tanaka classification system, Citrus tangerina is considered a separate species.</p>
  </div>

  <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-3" class="input"/>
  <label for="tab-3" class="label">Clemantine</label>
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Clemantine</h1>
    <p>A clementine (Citrus ×clementina) is a hybrid between a mandarin orange and a sweet orange, so named in 1902. The exterior is a deep orange colour with a smooth, glossy appearance. Clementines can be separated into 7 to 14 segments. Similarly to tangerines, they tend to be easy to peel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use relative position to overlap the tab button and the tab content. This way you can hide the top border of the tab content behind the tab button. It's kind of tricky, but it works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .tabs {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width: 700px;
            background: #efefef;
        }
        
        .input {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .label {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 30px;
            background: #e5e5e5;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #7f7f7f;
            transition: background 0.1s, color 0.1s;
        }
        
        .label:hover {
            background: #d8d8d8;
        }
        
        .label:active {
            background: #ccc;
        }
        
        .input:focus + .label {
            z-index: 1;
            border-bottom: -2px solid red;
        }
        
        .input:checked + .label {
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
            border: 1px solid green;
            border-bottom-color: white;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        @media (min-width: 600px) {
            .label {
                width: auto;
            }
        }
        
        .panel {
            display: none;
            padding: 20px 30px 30px;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        
        @media (min-width: 600px) {
            .panel {
                order: 99;
            }
        }
        
        .input:checked + .label + .panel {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            top: -1px;
            z-index: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="tabs">
        <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-1" checked="checked" class="input"/>
        <label for="tab-1" class="label">Orange</label>
        <div class="panel">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>The orange (specifically, the sweet orange) is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus × sinensis in the family Rutaceae</p>
            <p>The fruit of the Citrus × sinensis is considered a sweet orange, whereas the fruit of the Citrus × aurantium is considered a bitter orange. The sweet orange reproduces asexually (apomixis through nucellar embryony); varieties of sweet orange arise through mutations.</p>
        </div>
        
        <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-2" class="input"/>
        <label for="tab-2" class="label">Tangerine</label>
        <div class="panel">
            <h1>Tangerine</h1>
            <p>The tangerine (Citrus tangerina) is an orange-colored citrus fruit that is closely related to, or possibly a type of, mandarin orange (Citrus reticulata).</p>
            <p>The name was first used for fruit coming from Tangier, Morocco, described as a mandarin variety. Under the Tanaka classification system, Citrus tangerina is considered a separate species.</p>
        </div>
        
        <input name="tabs" type="radio" id="tab-3" class="input"/>
        <label for="tab-3" class="label">Clemantine</label>
        <div class="panel">
            <h1>Clemantine</h1>
            <p>A clementine (Citrus ×clementina) is a hybrid between a mandarin orange and a sweet orange, so named in 1902. The exterior is a deep orange colour with a smooth, glossy appearance. Clementines can be separated into 7 to 14 segments. Similarly to tangerines, they tend to be easy to peel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I only modify this two sets of rules:

```
.input:checked + .label {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.input:checked + .label + .panel {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. What about "whiting" out the unused top tab space?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What space?

Comment: It was in the         .tabs {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width: 700px;
            background: #efefef;  (Changed this to #fff)
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
.label{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.input:checked + .label{
    border-left: 1px solid green;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    border-right: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.panel{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px; // increase when your border size increase
    z-index: 1;
}
```